# Get data inside JSON format in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, flask-restful

I am making a GET request to retrieve data while using POSTMAN to check for the response.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from flask import jsonify

db_connect = create_engine('sqlite:///quiz.db')
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Quiz(Resource):
    def get(self, quiz_id):
        conn = db_connect.connect()
        query = conn.execute("select * from quiz where id =%d "  %int(quiz_id))
        result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in query.cursor]}
        return jsonify(result)

api.add_resource(Quiz, '/api/quiz/<quiz_id>') # Route_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5002')
```

Here's the response that I'm getting:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "description": "I love Python",
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Python"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's what I want:

```
{
    "description": "I love Python",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Python"
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? didn't `result['data']` help you?

Comment: access to value of key data ->result['data'][0]

Comment: @ncica result['data'][0] worked like a charm. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    result = {'data': [{'description': 'I love Python', 'name': 'Python', 'id': 2}]}
    result["another_data"] = [{ "description": "I love C","id": 3, "name": "C"}]
    for k in result.keys():
         print(result[k])
```

Above code will result what you looking for, as showing below.

```
    [{'description': 'I love Python', 'name': 'Python', 'id': 2}]
    [{'description': 'I love C', 'name': 'C', 'id': 3}]
```

Comment: Need to remove square braces as well.

Comment: `for k in result.keys():  print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in result[k] ) )`  and this will remove  square braces.